# Qt | SQLite Database executes every command twice

Tags: qt, command, execute

Hope you can help me with that problem, basically it's fast explained.
I made a database connection to a SQLite database and wrote a simple function that will return the database so I can just use "db()" instead of declaring it again.
This worked for other projects before and I just copied the most part of it, so I don't realy know where it went wrong....but every command I wan't to execute is executed twice.

localdatabase.h

```
#ifndef LOCALDATABASE_H
#define LOCALDATABASE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QStringList>

class LocalDatabase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LocalDatabase(QObject *parent = 0);
    void initialize();
    bool insertHashValues(QStringList allHash);

private:
    QSqlDatabase db();
};

#endif // LOCALDATABASE_H
```

localdatabase.cpp

```
#include "localdatabase.h"

LocalDatabase::LocalDatabase(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

QSqlDatabase LocalDatabase::db()
{
    return QSqlDatabase::database();
}

void LocalDatabase::initialize()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:/temp/data.db");
    db.setConnectOptions("Count Changes=off;pooling=true;Cache Size=10000;Page Size=4096;Synchronous=off;");
}

bool LocalDatabase::insertHashValues(QStringList allHash)
{
    bool result = true;

    if(!db().open()) return false;
    db().transaction();

    foreach(QString hash, allHash)
    {
        QSqlQuery q("INSERT INTO hash (hash) VALUES ('" + hash + "');", db());

        if(!q.exec())
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    db().commit();
    db().close();

    return result;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "localdatabase.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    LocalDatabase ldb;
    ldb.initialize();

//  ***
//  Writing Hash-Keys into the StringList "allHash"
//  ***

    ldb.insertHashValues(allHash);

    return a.exec();
}
```

The StringList "allHash" contains about 160,000 Hash-Values....also checked this in debug.
This should lead to 160,000 entrys in the database, but at the end I have 320,000 executed querys.

The database then looks like this:

id;hash
1;f8j39fh3fdh34fg3h4fgtrgr
2;f8j39fh3fdh34fg3h4fgtrgr
3;3freferff343t65j8j787k8k
4;3freferff343t65j8j787k8k
5;h67hgigjggjjonnmkcbldjjs
6;h67hgigjggjjonnmkcbldjjs

I don't know why it does that.
Tried do change the foreach to a while-loop with an explicit integer counting to 160,000, so it won't execute the commands more often than this....still the same outcome.
Did I mess up the database declaration somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery ( const QString & query = QString(), QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase() )` method documentation:

> If query is not an empty string, it will be executed.

So if you specify a database to the constructor, the query will be executed immediately. You should not call `exec` after that. You can use `QSqlQuery::isActive` to check if a query was successful.

Also I think you should create a class member for your `QSqlDatabase` object, initialize it in `init()` and return it in `db()`. It will be more clear because it's hard to understand what `QSqlDatabase::database` does without reading its documentation. Also `QSqlDatabase::database` creates some small but unnecessary overhead. You're not supposed to call it so many times.